# Firebase Real Time Database Patch Data Scheduled Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I using Firebase Real-Time Database.
My example structure:

```
fruits:{
     apple:{
           soldAllTime:500
           Verify:true
           soldDaily:30
          },
     banana:{
           soldAllTime:350
           Verify:true
           soldDaily:27
          },
}
```

II want all 'soldDaily's to be reset at 00:00 UTC every day. What is the easiest and most logical way?

I reading docs but not have about Update data with Schedule

functions/index.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp({

databaseURL: "https://...."
});

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('* * * * *').onRun(() => {

  return admin.database().ref('/fruits/soldDaily').patch({
    'soldDaily':0

  }).then(() => {
    console.log('Success');
    
    return {
        console.log(success)
    };
  })
  return null;
});
```

This not working.
How should I edit this?

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description. What *does* it do? Why is that *wrong*? What *should* happen instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write any value to the database, you need to know the full path that you want to write it to.

So in your use-case, you'll need to:

1. Read the fruits into your application code.
2. Loop over the fruits to get their individual keys.
3. Update the `soldDaily` of each individual fruit.

---

In general I prefer to not have counters that I need to reset, so I'd consider a data structure that makes the CRON update unneeded. For example if you store sales by day:

```
dailySales: {
  "2021-06-17": {
    "apple": 30,
    "banana": 27
  },
  "2021-06-18": {
    "apple": 1
  }
}
```

With this structure there is never a need to reset the data, and you can always simply increment the count for the current day (as determined by your application code that does the increment).

Comment: thank you. How can i create Date structure id?

Comment: Are you asking: [how to format a date into a certain string format in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+format+a+date+string+in+Node.js)

Comment: Hey @OrhanAteş Anything else needed here?

Comment: Sorry Dear Puff. This is solved my problem. I create new Json for daily. Thanks

Comment: Great to hear that you got it working @OrhanAteş 